# How does getline work with cin?

Tags: c++, input, stream

I feel like there are a lot of similar questions, so I'm really sorry if this is a duplicate.  I couldn't find the answer to this specific question, though.

I am confused as to how getline works when cin is passed to it, because my understanding is that it should be calling cin each time it is called.  When working with code that was in a book I'm reading though, getline is called several times yet only one input is sent.  The cin object is not called from anywhere except for within these getline calls.

What's going on here?  When getline is reached does the program simply stop in its tracks and wait for the input stream to pass a value including the desired delimiter?  If this is the case, do the subsequent getline calls just not have to wait because the input stream already has data including their respective delimiters?  I ran a couple tests that would suggest this could be the case.

**Here is the code:**

```
    string firstName;
    getline(cin,firstName,',');

    string lastName;
    getline(cin,lastName,',');

    string job;
    getline(cin,job,'\n');

    cout<<firstName<<" "<<lastName<<" is a "<<job<<endl;;
```

Sorry again if this is a stupid question, but I looked around and genuinely could not find the answer.  Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided!

**Clarification:**

This code outputs "First Last is a Job" for the console input "First,Last,Job\n"

Comment: Each one extracts everything up to and including the delimiter so there's no way it'll still be there for the next call.

Comment: @chris Unless there's more than one delimiter, since it stops at the first one.

Comment: @JS What do you mean by saying "only one input is sent"?

Comment: @ooga I clarified at the end of the post.

Comment: @ooga, True, I guess it's always possible to input more than necessary :P And I guess that's what the question is getting at, too.

Comment: @chris That's the whole point of this code though, it was just supposed to be showing me how to do a bit of string parsing using getline - unfortunately, it confused me because the book never properly explained how the iostream works!

Comment: @JS, Unfortunately, there are many levels of explanation of IO streams, varying from simple to extremely complex. Perhaps the book goes into more detail later.

Comment: @chris Thankfully ye good folks at ol' StackOverflow were able to help me, but I'm 200 pages in and see nothing in the table of contents to suggest it will be touched on!  It is possible, but this book has a tendency to leave things like that out so far, it seems.

Comment: @JS, Well, I would be lying if I said you can become proficient with C++ after just one book :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A call to a function using `cin` is not actually a request for user input (at least not directly). It is a request for characters from the standard input. In normal program operation (where standard input is not being directed from a file or other source) standard input is stored in a buffer. If the standard input buffer is empty, and `cin` is requesting more characters, then your system will request input from the user via the terminal. (i.e. the keyboard). This input which the terminal requests is generally line oriented. That is, it waits for you to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, then sends all the data to be stored in the standard input buffer. If `cin` gets all the characters it needs before the input buffer is empty, those characters remain until the next request.

So, for example, when you make this call:

```
getline(cin,firstName,',');
```

and the input buffer is empty, Let's say the user inputs this:

> > Benjamin, Lindley, Software Developer<kbd>Enter</kbd>

First, the following string is stored in the input buffer:

```
"Benjamin, Lindley, Software Developer\n"
```

Then `getline` causes `"Benjamin,"` to be read from the input buffer (but discards the comma).

```
" Lindley, Software Developer\n"
```

remains in the buffer for any future operations with `cin`.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are confirming my original guess that the program stops and waits until proper input has been received if it doesn't see the delimiter in the current input stream?

Comment: I have no idea how I ended up with the checkmark! And how did you get that Enter key to look like that?

Comment: @ooga: `<kbd>Enter</kbd>`

Comment: I don't know what to do, I feel bad!  I originally gave you the checkmark but switched it because your answer was equivalent to  ooga's and ooga helped me first up in the comments, but then you updated your answer to be more extensive!

Answer (score 4):

`getline` does not "call" `cin` at all. `cin` is an object. Objects contain data. The data in `cin` is the information needed by input functions to read the standard input stream. If you wanted to read from a file, for instance, you'd open the file and pass the file object to `getline` instead.

When `getline` is called, the program reads whatever is in the input buffer. If the input buffer already contains the delimiter then `getline` will return right away. Otherwise it will wait.

Comment: So then if the input delimiter does not contain the delimiter when that line is reached, the entire program will freeze and only continue when proper input has been received from the stream?

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help!  I originally accepted Benjamin Lindley's answer, but I retracted it (sorry Benjamin) because I saw your name.  I figured you deserved it since you responded to me before him up in the comments.  Thanks again!

Comment: His was more complete ... but I'll take it! I'll give him a +1 to make up for it a little. :-)

Comment: Ahh, I don't know what to do now to be fair!  Haha when I switched the checkmark to you I didn't realize he had extended his answer.

Comment: His answer is more complete. I suggest switching it back. No hard feelings!

Comment: Alright, I did so.  Such diplomacy.  Much nice.  Wow.