# NOTE:(getline was not the issue) C++ getline() stops working in user defined function but works in main function

Tags: c++, find

NOTE: SOLVED, problem was not getline() but find function with an
Improperly filled array!

I've looked up several questions before posting my own, but I could not find an answer for my problem. This is my first question posted, but I did do some research and tried other solutions from other questions before posting my own. So I am not entirely sure this isn't a duplicate. My apologies! Thank you for understanding in advance!

I am trying to use getline() (c++) to get user input. It works fine in my main, but does not in my user defined function. I thought it might have to do with the buffer, so i used cin.ignore() as suggested in:

[C++ getline method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257205/c-getline-method-not-working)

and i checked:

[How does getline work with cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654444/c-how-does-getline-work-with-cin)

to make sure I properly understood getline(). However my program still does not work correctly.

My program takes English Text as a string from user input (console input) and converts it into Morse Code and outputs result as a string (console output).

basically my problem is this:

getline works in my main function for both strings and strings with spaces ex: "This" and "This Code".

However, in my user defined function, it ONLY works for strings without spaces ex: "This".

Thanks for the help! Code snippets below!

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <ctype.h>;

using namespace std;


string textToMorse(const string alphabet, const string morseAlphabet[]);

int main()
{
    const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,?";
    const string morseAlphabet[39] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","
    ..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.",
    "--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","-----",".----","..---",
    "...--","....-",".....",
    "-....","--...","---..","----.",".-.-.-","--..--","..--.."};
    int userSelection;
    string resultString;


    cout << "TEXT TO MORSE CODE or MORSE CODE TO TEXT program" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please select an option by typing the integer shown: " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Type(Selects option) 1 to decode Morse code to English text" << endl;
    cout << "Type(Selects option) 2 to encode English text to Morse code" << endl;
    cout << "Type(Select option) any other integer that is NOT 1 or 2 to QUIT" << endl << endl;
    cin >> userSelection;

   while(userSelection == 1 || userSelection == 2)
   {

        if(userSelection == 1)
        {

            resultString = textToMorse(alphabet, morseAlphabet); // function where I use 
                                                                 // getline() but does not work
            cout << endl << "This is the Morse code decoded to English text: " << endl << endl;
            cout << resultString << endl << endl << endl << endl;
        }
   }

    return 0;
}

// does not work
string textToMorse(const string alphabet, const string morseAlphabet[])
{
    string userInput;
    cout << endl << "Enter English text to encode to Morse code,
    with only a space between words: " << endl << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,userInput); //code works with strings without spaces, 
                            //but breaks with others. ex: "This" works as input
                            //but "This code" breaks and the console seems to freeze
                            // then crashes out

    cin.clear();

    // rest of code, but program breaks before this.

    string encodedEnglishText = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
    {
        userInput[i] = toupper(userInput[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
    {
       encodedEnglishText += morseAlphabet[alphabet.find(userInput[i])];
       encodedEnglishText += " "; // extra spacing added for output clarity

       if(userInput[i] == ' ')
       {
           encodedEnglishText += "  "; // extra spacing added for output clarity
       }
    }

    return encodedEnglishText;
}
```

However if I edit my code and get the input from my main and pass it in as a parameter, it works.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <ctype.h>;

using namespace std;


string textToMorse(const string alphabet, const string morseAlphabet[], string userInput);
int main()
{
    const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789.,?";
    const string morseAlphabet[39] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","
    ..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.",
    "--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","-----",".----","..---",
    "...--","....-",".....",
    "-....","--...","---..","----.",".-.-.-","--..--","..--.."};
    int userSelection;
    string resultString;


    cout << "TEXT TO MORSE CODE or MORSE CODE TO TEXT program" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please select an option by typing the integer shown: " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Type(Selects option) 1 to decode Morse code to English text" << endl;
    cout << "Type(Selects option) 2 to encode English text to Morse code" << endl;
    cout << "Type(Select option) any other integer that is NOT 1 or 2 to QUIT" << endl << endl;
    cin >> userSelection;

   while(userSelection == 1 || userSelection == 2)
   {

        if(userSelection == 1)
        {
            string userInput;
            cout << endl << "Enter English text to encode to Morse code,
            with only a space between words: " << endl << endl;

            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin,userInput); //code works with both "This" and "This code"

            cin.clear();
            resultString = textToMorse(alphabet, morseAlphabet, userInput); //function modified 
                                                                           //to take one more
                                                                           //parameter
            cout << endl << "This is the Morse code decoded to English text: " << endl << endl;
            cout << resultString << endl << endl << endl << endl;
        }
   }

    return 0;
}

string textToMorse(const string alphabet, const string morseAlphabet[], string userInput)
{
    //code, but program works.

    string encodedEnglishText = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
    {
        userInput[i] = toupper(userInput[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
    {
       encodedEnglishText += morseAlphabet[alphabet.find(userInput[i])];
       encodedEnglishText += " "; // extra spacing added for output clarity

       if(userInput[i] == ' ')
       {
           encodedEnglishText += "  "; // extra spacing added for output clarity
       }
    }

    return encodedEnglishText;
}
```

I didn't include all of the code, just the parts I felt were relevant to the question.

by works I mean:

getline successfully takes input. getline successfully assigns a string such as "this" and "this code" to the variable userInput when used in main function.

it only successfully assigns strings without spaces such as "this" when used in my user defined function. In that function, for some reason it does not work when I enter a string like "this code" or any string with a space inbetween.

note: program is not finished, as I plan to add other methods to do the reverse (as seen in code with 
extra user options, but these are not yet implemented or defined, code still runs and compiles for problem I am facing.

Comment: In your first example you call `morseToText`, not `textToMorse`. Is it a typo?

Comment: One thing I suspect is that you are somehow exceeding the end of your morseAlphabet array.  Are you sure it crashes before the "rest of code"?  One way to determine where it is crashing is to put cout statements throughout your code to debug, but hopefully your debugger can be more helpful than that.  If you are using Linux, valgrind can be quite helpful to determine where the program crashes.

Comment: I did try this, I am using Code::Blocks on Windows 8.1. But the array seems to work fine!

Comment: I fixed your code so it would compile and it crashes because there is no space character in `alphabet` so `find` returns `std::string::npos` and attempts to index way out of bounds into `morseAlphabet`.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed this was not a problem however, as it works in my main with the exact same code (array not changed in main yet still works with spaces) but this does fix it in my function! Would there by any reason as to why it would work in main() and not in my function without the space in the array?

Comment: I tested the code you say works and it failed at exactly the same place with the same input "dog cat".  The only explanation I have for you is that you either weren't testing with the same input or, since this is undefined behavior it just didn't crash when the code was slightly rearranged.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it on a different machine and I see what you mean. Regardless, I updated my code as suggested and the problem is fixed! Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no morse code for a space.

Make a verification:

```
    int n = alphabet.find(userInput[i]);
    encodedEnglishText += (n == string::npos) ? "  ":  morseAlphabet[n];
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks!  it works in my main with the exact same code (array not changed in main yet still works with spaces)  this does fix it in my function though! Would there by any reason as to why it would work in main() and not in my function without the space in the array? - both Retired Ninja and Christophe gave similar answers, so thank you to you both.

Comment: That's the joy of "Undefined Behaviour" when trying to access an invalid object: same code may generate different symptoms, sometimes it even seems to work. That's because all depends on what the code will find in the memory it accesses.  This is why these bugs are nasty and hard to discover.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking for your input character in the `alphabet` string you won't find `' '` and `std::string::find()` return `std::string::npos` (normally `-1` converted to the type `std::string::size_type` but the value isn't guaranteed). Using this value to index `morseAlphabet` won't do you much good: it is undefined behavior. This problem does not arise when you enter just one string as all characters are found in `alphabet`.

The proper way to deal with the situation is to look for the character and capture the result. Before using the result, you'd test the input, e.g.:

```
std::string::size_type pos(alphabet.find(userInput[i]));
if (pos == std::string::npos) {
    // deal with the character not being part of the alphabet
}
else {
    encodedEnglishText += morseAlphabet[pos];
}
```

Note that there are a few other things wrong with your program:

1. The selection of options should be *inside* the loop! The way it is implemented entering, e.g. `2` results in an infinite loop.
2. Using `std::toupper()` with a `char` can also result in undefined behavior! The problem is that `std::toupper()` expects a non-negative value of the value `EOF` but `char` may be signed. To avoid this problem you should use any of the functions from `<cctype>` or `<ctype.h>` with `unsigned char`:

   ```
   userInput[i] = toupper[static_cast<unsigned char>(userInput[i]));
   ```
3. If the user doesn't enter an integer but, e.g., `foo` reading `userSelection` will fail and stream will get into failure state where it won't do anything until `std::cin.clear()` is entered. The best approach to deal with this situation is to test the result of reading the value before doing anything. If the input failed you can recover from the situation by clearing the status and skipping the offending character, e.g.:

   ```
   if (std::cin >> userSelection) {
       // use the selection
   }
   else {
       std::cout << "ignoring invalid input\n";
       std::cin.clear();
       std::cin.ignore();
   }
   ```

   Note that your use of `std::cin.clear()` should be needed. Also, you should verify that the input you read with `std::getline()` is successful: in general, all user inputs should be tested for success.
4. If you enter a space character after the integer when reading `userSelection`, your call to `std::cin.ignore()` will ignore this space not the newline! To avoid this problem you could either read all charactors up to the first newline or skip all whitespace prior to the non-whitespace character:

   ```
   std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // all till newline
   std::cin >> std::ws; // skip all whitespace to first non-whitespace character
   ```
5. [Do **not** use `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/)! It does not only create a newline but it also flushes the stream. This can easily create a performance problem.
6. You should probably pass `std::string` arguments by reference rather than by value. Passing the argument `alphabet` by value creates a copy with is inefficient (the `morseAlphabet` argument is passed by pointer although it looks like an array).
7. Some string literals seem to be split across multiple lines. Doing so is illegal (I guess, however, that this problem was introduced when pasting the code to the question above at some point).

Comment: Dietmar Kühl, thank you for your very detailed answer! I am new to c++, as I usually program in Java, so there is still a lot of conventions I need to learn, thank you for the input and the great answer!